# C# 4: Raising and Subscribing Events Between Static CLasses

Tags: c#

I've spent the last couple days reading my various books and looking through MSDN's documentation and I just cannot get what seems like an overwhelmingly simple task to work.

Here's what I want to do in a nutshell: I have a static class, DBToolBox that runs various functions on SQL databases, and I want it to have an error reporting system that stands apart from the UI. I want to use an event to signal when the log (a DataTable) has been updated so that another static class, a windows form with a DataGridView on it, will refresh itself.
Here's the code I can't get to work:

The Signaling Class:

```
public static class DBTools
{
public static readonly DataTable ErrorLog = new DataTable();
public static event EventHandler LogUpdated = delegate {};
// the actual functionality of the class

    private static void Error(Exception Ex, string MethodName)  
    {


        ErrorLog.Rows.Add((); 
        //logs the error with a bunch of data that I'm not listing here 

        LogUpdated(null, EventArgs.Empty); //I attempt to raise an event


    }

 }
```

The Reacting Class:

```
public static partial class ErrorWindow : Form
{

    DBToolbox.LogUpdated += ErrorWindow.ErrorResponse; 
    \\the offending event handler:
             \\invalid token "+=" in class, struct, or interface member declaration
             \\invalid token ";" in class, struct, or interface member declaration
             \\'QueryHelper_2._0.DBToolbox.LogUpdated' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
             \\'QueryHelper_2._0.ErrorWindow.ErrorResponse(object)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'



      private void Error_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ErrorLogView.DataSource = DBToolbox.ErrorLog;

    }

    public void ErrorResponse(object sender)
    {
        this.Show();
        this.ErrorLogView.DataSource = DBToolbox.ErrorLog;
        this.ErrorLogView.Refresh();
        this.Refresh();
    }

}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Also, there are two other solution to do what I'm looking for:
The first is the DataTable's own events RowUpdated or NewTableRow, but I'm not sure how to subsribe to that event.

The other is the DataGridVeiw's DataSourceChanged event, but I dont know if that means the event fires when the DataSource's address changes, of if it's values change.

I'm also about a week and a half into my C# career, but I programmed with VB2010 for about a year before this, so I'm mildly familiar with .NET 4's function library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: `partial` classes are only static if *all* parts are declared as such.  Also (as far as I know, as I currently don't have the means to test it) `static` classes can neither be inherited by nor themselves inherit another class.
And last but not least: UI element derivatives *always* need instantiated classes as all underlying stuff is instance based.

And to attach your event handler to the event, you need to do so inside a method body (i.e. in the constructor):

```
public ErrorWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // Needed to init Winforms stuff
    DBToolbox.LogUpdated += ErrorResponse;
}
```

Additionally you'd have to change the `ErrorResponse` event handler to match the `void EventHandler(object, EventArgs)` signature.

Comment: YES! I tried this, tinkered with it for a few moments and it works. It's so beautiful I could cry.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
DBToolbox.LogUpdated += ErrorWindow.ErrorResponse;
```

needs to be in a method. Try adding a static constructor to ErrorWindow that includes that line.

```
static ErrorWindow()
{
  DBToolbox.LogUpdated += ErrorWindow.ErrorResponse;
}
```

Comment: +1 as I didn't notice that line was not inside a method when I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.ErrorLogView.DataBind()` after you set the DataSource.